# Integrate a function with sympy.integrate

Tags: python, sympy

I'm approximating an integral using Lagrange polynomials. I have correctly set up the polynomial but I encountered some issues in the last step:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import axes as ax
import sympy
####Pyplot font settings

nvect = np.array([5, 15, 30, 50])
#Left and right bounds of interploation points
xl = -5; xr=5;
xs = sympy.Symbol('X')

fcn = 1/(1+xs**2) # to be integrated from -5 to 5
int_exact = sympy.integrate(fcn,(xs,xl,xr))

f = sympy.lambdify(xs,fcn)

#Error vector
err = np.zeros(len(nvect))
#Interpolation
plt.figure(figsize=(8,10))
for j in range(0,len(nvect)):
#Current n:
    n = nvect[j] #n is the number of intervals.
    
    na = 1001 #Number of points to plot approximation
    xj = np.linspace(xl,xr,n+1) #equispaced points
    xx = np.linspace(xl,xr,na) #points to plot approximation
    
    intval = 0
    for i in range(0,n+1):
        L_i = 1;
        for k in range(0,n+1):
            if k!=i:
                L_i = L_i*(xs-xj[k])/(xj[i]-xj[k]) #symbolic form
        
        Li_int = sympy.integrate(f(i)*L_i[i],(xs,xl,xr))
        #Li = sympy.lambdify(xs,Li_int)
        intval = intval + Li_int
   
    err[j] = np.abs(int_exact-intval)
    
plt.scatter(nvect,err,color='r',s=150,label='Global,equispaced points')
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
Li_int = sympy.integrate(f(i)*L_i[i],(xs,xl,xr))

TypeError: 'Mul' object is not subscriptable
```

I can't figure out how to solve this issue
[image]

Comment: I see one subscript/indexing step in that expression, `L_i[i]`.  What is `L_i`?  Tell us if it makes sense to index it.

Comment: `L_i = L_i*(xs-xj[k])/(xj[i]-xj[k]) #symbolic form`

Comment: I can read that.  I want you to examine it - print the result - and tell us why you think it can be indexed  Better yet show us the print.

Comment: L_i is the lagrange polynomial